# Using a channel for multiple commands, replys, and interactive commands?

Tags: python, ssh, twisted

I'm beginning to learn twisted.conch to automate some tasks over SSH.

`I tried to modify` the sample sshclient.py from http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/SSH-with-Twisted/4/ . It runs 1 command after login and prints captured output.

`What I wanted to do` is to run a series commands, and maybe decide what to do based on the output.

`The problem I ran into` is that **twisted.conch.ssh.channel.SSHChannel** appears to be always closing itself after running a command (such as *df -h*). The example will **sendRequest** after **channelOpen**. Then the channel is always closed after **dataReceived** no matter what I did.

I'm wondering if this is due to server sending an EOF after the command. And therefore this channel must be closed? Should I just open multiple channels for multiple commands?

`Another problem is` those interactive commands (such as *rm -i somefile*). It seems that because the server didn't send EOF, **SSHChannel.dataReceived** never gets called. How do I manage to capture output in this situation, and what do I do to send back a response?

Comment: I'd like to clarify that "running a series of commands" is similar to the *expect* command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I just open multiple channels for multiple commands?

Yep.  That's how SSH works.

> SSHChannel.dataReceived never gets called

This doesn't sound like what should happen.  Perhaps you can include a minimal example which reproduces the behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To reproduce the behavior you only need to use the code from http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/SSH-with-Twisted/4/ and run the *rm -i somefile* command. dataReceived should print whatever is received, I'm seeing nothing.

Comment: Ah.  This is because `rm -i somefile` writes its prompt to stderr.  These bytes aren't delivered to the `dataReceived` callback, but instead to the `extReceived` callback.  Enabling Twisted logging (twisted.python.log.startLogging) will cause the SSH client to dump lots of extra information about what's happening, and might help you track down other similar problems.

Comment: Yes. It is the `extReceived` callback. Thanks for the logging tip.